# Getting the percentage of a relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Orders have many `line_items`, which in turn have an `employee_id` and `amount_cents`. In the second line of this query, I try creating a `line_item_perc` variable by gathering all the `line_items` with a certain `employee_id` and dividing their `amounts_cents` by all the other `line_items`:

```
Order.joins(:tips, :line_items)
.select('line_items WHERE(custom_attributes -> "employee_id" = ?) AS employee_line_items,
  SUM(employee_line_items.amount_cents) / SUM(line_items.amount_cents) AS line_item_perc',
  params[:employee_id])
.sum('tips.amount_cents * line_item_perc')
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The select statement doesn't even appear in the final SQL. (I'm assuming this is because `sum` overwrites it.) So what else could I do to get `line_item_perc`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def line_item_percent(employee_id, line_item_id)
  total_amount_in_cents = Order.joins(:line_items).where("employee_id = ?", employee_id).pluck(:amount_cents).sum
  line_item_cents = LineItem.find(line_item_id).amount_cents
  answer = line_item_cents / total_amount_in_cents
end #returns decimal
```

Try this. Did it off top of head with rails not SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response, though unfortunately this solution won't work. The crux is that orders have many line_items, which will lead to a pretty substantial N+1 problem here. Another issue is that the employee_id is on the line_item, not the order itself. Thanks for attempting this, though. And if you have any further suggestions, I'd love to hear them.